# jQuery: duration param fail in .animate() method

Tags: jquery

The settings I set in the duration params in the following code are failing me (50, 1000, 4000). No matter the duration value I set it runs at a speed that looks to be half a second. Here is a link to a live demo - http://dekke.net/easing/easing.html. Here is the relevant code:

```
        $(function() {
        $("#animate").click(function() {
            $("#one").animate({ left: "500px" }, { duration: "50", easing: "linear"}, 0);
            $("#two").delay(500).animate({ left: "500px" }, { duration: "1000", easing: "linear"} ); 
            $("#three").delay(1000).animate({ left: "500px" }, { duration: "4000", easing: "linear"} );
        });
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a string:

```
duration:"1000"
```

pass a number:

```
duration:1000
```

---

**EDIT:** A little more information.

Here's where the `duration` is analyzed. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5/src/effects.js#L283-284

Basically -

- if it's a Number, use it
- if not, assume it is a property of `jQuery.fx.speeds` ("slow", "fast")
- if not, use the `_default` property of `jQuery.fx.speeds`

I'd think it would be useful if jQuery would attempt a `parseInt()` if it wasn't a Number just in case someone did pass a numeric string. Then if that returns `NaN`, try the `jQuery.fx.speeds`.

Comment: +1 yeah that is the issue, thanks for the extra object tip. http://jsfiddle.net/DU8hP/